# javafx root -fx-font-size and em sizing

Tags: javafx, font-size

I'm trying to resize my layout elements using a root font-size and 'em' values. It looks like whenever I "touch" the -fx-font-size attribute, the root's font size is being reset to the base value (1em = 12px).

For the simple fxml:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="mainStack" prefWidth="600" prefHeight="400" stylesheets="/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <left>
      <VBox fx:id="leftPane">
         <Button text="btn1"></Button>
         <Button text="btn2" styleClass="textBigger"></Button>
         <Button text="btn3"></Button>
      </VBox>
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

and css like:

```
.root {
    -fx-font-size: 10px;
    -fx-background-color: Lime;
}
#leftPane {
    /*-fx-font-size: 10px;*/
    -fx-background-color: Green;
    -fx-pref-width: 40em;
    -fx-spacing: 1em;
}
.button {
    -fx-background-color: Yellow;
    -fx-pref-height: 5em;
    -fx-pref-width: 20em;
}

#leftPane .textBigger {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

sample 1 is for root -fx-font-size = 10
sample 2 is for root -fx-font-size = 20

[image]

Button 1 and 3 as well as overall layout are as expected, but on button 2 pref-width and pref-height are being seized as multiplication of 12 instead of 10 or 20. So button 2 size is always 240x60.

Am I doing something wrong here? Does someone know a solution on how to prevent root -fx-font-size "reset"?

Comment: That looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I found a partial walkthrough for this, however it's really nasty and needs additional work to work. If it's about button, the text value can be left null and instead of this, Label can be inserted inside the <graphic> element of button. Setting .button .label {-fx-font-size: 2em} doesn't break the width and height sizing and the final result is as expected. Still it's not a good solution and it doesn't work with Label itself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is the BUG by the the javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper, look at the the code-line 1388:

```
boolean isFontProperty = "-fx-font".equals(property) || "-fx-font-size".equals(property);
```

then  1392:

```
boolean isRelative = ParsedValueImpl.containsFontRelativeSize(resolved, isFontProperty);
```

and 1444:

```
// did we get a fontValue from the preceding block?
// if not, get it from our cacheEntry or choose the default
if (fontForFontRelativeSizes == null) {
    if (fontFromCacheEntry != null && fontFromCacheEntry.isRelative() == false) {
        fontForFontRelativeSizes = (Font)fontFromCacheEntry.getValue();
    } else {
        fontForFontRelativeSizes = Font.getDefault();
    }
}
```

It must be fixed under the https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/submit_start.do, ID: 9055560.

As a workaround - to define -fx-font-size: XXXem; not in a .control-class, but deeply, for example in the .text-class, in your case:

```
#leftPane .textBigger .text {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Then the -fx-font-size: 2em; belongs only to the .text-class and doesn’t influence on the higher .textBigger-class.