# JavaFX - increase and decrease text size dynamic using CSS and FXML

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, font-size

I would like to be able to dynamically change font size in a TextArea by percentage. Between 25% - 225%. Eventually this setting will be loaded from a configuration file.

Current code in FXML:
`<TextArea fx:id="txtDescription" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="471.0" prefWidth="1036.0" />`

Current code in CSS:
`.text-area { -fx-font-size: 25; }`

In MainController.class I have imported the reference
`@FXML  private TextArea txtDescription;`

But if I try to retrieve information as below in a simple way, I get none...

`System.out.println("Get Style: " + txtDescription.getStyle()); System.out.println("Get StyleNode: " + txtDescription.getStyleableNode());`

What steps do you need to take to dynamically change the font size?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java**

```java
double initialSize = 16.0; // 100% size
        
Slider slider = new Slider(25, 225, 100);
slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue) -> { 
     double fromPercent = (initialSize * newValue) / 100           
     txtDescription.setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + (int) fromPercent);
});
```

**For get font size**

```java
txtDescription.getFont().getSize();
```

For change without rewrite style

```java
    Font oldFont = txtDescription.getFont();
    Font newFontSize = new Font(txtDescription.getName(), newSize);
    txtDescription.setFont(newFontSize);
```

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response (y)

Comment: An example if this approach is in [javafx automatic resizing and button padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229149/javafx-automatic-resizing-and-button-padding).